# Hinduism and Buddhism

Tags: philosophy, buddhism

We all know Bhagwan Buddh was the incarnation of Great Lord Vishnu.

Vaishnav worship Lord Vishnu. Why did then Lord Vishnu created another Dharma? Why did not he rectified Hinduism?

Comment: 1- Gautam Buddha wasn't an incarnation of Lord Vishnu. Gautam Buddha explained his previous lives suggests he was normal being. 2- Gautam Buddha didn't create new religion. His followers did.

Comment: Had Gautam Buddha been an avatar, he would have mentioned his one of previous lives as Lord Rama or Krishna.

Comment: @Aghori Can you give prove of what you said?

Comment: @Aghori Adi Shankara in his Hari Shankara Stotram [mentions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11977/3872) Buddha as avatara of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: @Agohri there were two Buddhas in Kali yuga

Comment: Refer this answer . https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3574/10089         Hope this helps.