# Where can I find the audio of Hari Sankara stotra by Adi shankaracharya?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, stotra

I'm looking for the audio pronunciation of [Hari Sankara Stotra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/what-is-the-mystery-of-hari-sankara-stotra-composed-by-adi-shankara/11977#11977) .